# How do you get a Splunk forwarder to work with the main Splunk server?

Tags: splunk

I have installed Splunk version 7.3.2 on one server.  I have installed Splunk forwarder version 7.3.2 on a second server.  Both servers are running Ubuntu 18.

On the Splunk forwarder I ran these commands:

```
sudo /opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk add monitor /var/log/syslog -index main -sourcetype %app%

sudo /opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk add forward-server x.x.x.x:9997
```

(where x.x.x.x is the IP address of the Splunk server)

```
sudo /opt/splunk/bin/splunk start
```

I tried rebooting both servers and restarting Splunk on both.

From the Splunk dashboard I want to see some indication of the logs from the server with the forwarder.  But I don't see any. I log into the web UI, I go to Settings -> Monitoring Console ->  Indexing -> Indexes and Performance.  There is an "Instance" drop down menu.  But the only option I see is the Splunk server.  I do not see the forwarder.

If I go to Data Inputs in the web UI, I cannot click "Next."

How can I see some evidence that the Splunk web UI is receiving data from the Splunk forwarder?

I check network connectivity, and nothing is blocking TCP/IP communication between the two.  I would expect to see some forwarded data in Splunk (on the main Splunk server), but I am not seeing that.  What should I do?

Edit: Through the web UI for Splunk I configured a listening port for the forwarding on port 9997.  By running `splunk enable listen 9997` I get

> Failed to create. Configuration for port 9997 already exists.

Update on 10/9/19

Connectivity is configured over port 9997 between the two servers.  I have used nmap to test over this port to and from both servers using internal and external IP addresses.  Nothing is filtered over this port.  Therefore I am quite sure no firewall rule or security mechanism is to blame.  In fact, the back end splunk log for the main splunk server has registered some activity of the Splunk forwarder.

I am trying to index /var/log/* on my Splunk forwarder server.  Here is an excerpt from /opt/splunkforwarder/var/log/splunk/splunkd.log:

> 10-10-2019 00:21:18.059 +0000 INFO  WatchedFile - Will begin reading
>   at offset=4835872 for file='/var/log/sampleoct.log'. ... 10-10-2019
>   00:22:10.944 +0000 WARN  FileClassifierManager - The file
>   '/var/log/.test123.swp' is invalid. Reason: binary. 10-10-2019
>   00:22:10.944 +0000 INFO  TailReader - Ignoring file
>   '/var/log/.test123.swp' due to: binary 10-10-2019 00:22:10.945 +0000
>   WARN  FileClassifierManager - The file '/var/log/.test123.swp' is
>   invalid. Reason: binary. ... 10-10-2019 00:30:50.948 +0000 INFO 
>   TailReader - Ignoring file
>   '/var/log/journal/94b0369aaba948b4b6a6b43288cee7e6/system.journal' due
>   to: binary

In /var/log/ there is a non-binary file of text that I created.  It is 106 KB large.  On the Splunk server, I see no evidence that a second instance (e.g., the Splunk forwarder) is working.

On the Splunk server I see this in /opt/splunk/var/log/splunk/splunkd.log:

> 10-10-2019 00:21:09.930 +0000 WARN  DateParserVerbose - Accepted time
>   (Tue Oct  8 16:59:22 2019) is suspiciously far away from the previous
>   event's time (Wed Oct  9 23:48:21 2019), but still accepted because it
>   was extracted by the same pattern. Context:
>   source=/var/log/test123123|host=ip-123-123-123-1|%%app%%|125
>   10-10-2019 00:22:31.288 +0000 WARN  AggregatorMiningProcessor -
>   Breaking event because limit of 256 has been exceeded -
>   data_source="/var/log/test123", data_host="ip-123-123-123-1",
>   data_sourcetype="%app%" 10-10-2019 00:22:31.288 +0000 WARN 
>   AggregatorMiningProcessor - Changing breaking behavior for event
>   stream because MAX_EVENTS (256) was exceeded without a single event
>   break. Will set BREAK_ONLY_BEFORE_DATE to False, and unset any
>   MUST_NOT_BREAK_BEFORE or MUST_NOT_BREAK_AFTER rules. Typically this
>   will amount to treating this data as single-line only. -
>   data_source="/var/log/test123", data_host="ip-123-123-123-1",
>   data_sourcetype="%app%"

Where in the web UI should I look for this log file?  It seems like it may be indexed, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1):

On the Splunk Indexer, you need to tell it to listen for Splunk traffic. You can do this from the command line by typing `splunk enable listen 9997`.

Answer (score 1):

switch to root so that you don't have to enter your password for every command with:

```
sudo su
```

there are several things that could be occurring. I'll walk you through 3 things

1. splunk listening
2. splunk forwarding
3. splunk directory monitoring
4. Proper Search Query

After you have splunk running and you have logged in.

- Ensure that splunk is listening on port 9997, this can be done by
  going to the settings drop down menu in the top right  under "Data"
  select forwarding and receiving
- Under receiving data section click configure receiving

port 9997 should be listed with a status of enabled as such:
[image: picture showing successful listening on port 9997]

The second thing would be to ensure that your forwarder is setup correctly. We can validate that a forwarder is active with the following command (on the hosts' with splunk forwarders):

```
sudo /opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk list forward-server
```

this command will prompt you for your sudo password and then the username and password for splunk.
The results will list active forwarders. Please ensure that the one listed matches the host that has splunk running.
Forwarder should be listed in the format:

```
{ipv4}x:9997
```

3rd

let's make sure that we have log monitoring setup correctly
on the host with the following command

```
sudo /opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk list monitor
```

the result will list monitored directories and monitored files. Make sure that you see the log file or director for which you would like to monitor.

4th

In the Splunk UI under Search and reporting, your search query cannot be simply "syslog"
being that syslog is director or a sourcetype your query must either be
 `sourcetype=syslog` or `source="/var/log/syslog"`
further refinement can be added to the search query, such as host

If all of this checks out, then I would suggest deleting the forwarder and reinstalling, as there may have been unwanted modifications to your inputs.conf and outputs.conf

Another tip is that if you make changes to the splunk forwarder, remember to restart your splunk forwarder to ensure changes take effect.
the command to restart the splunk forwarder is:

```
/opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain there are no local firewalls on the instances? Can you provide the splunkd.log file from the forwarder, as that will have information about why the data isn't flowing. This may be a permission issue on reading the files, network issue due to local firewalls or routing, or some other issues.